# Scala covariance assignment to super type

Tags: scala, covariance, contravariance

I am trying to figure out scala covariance and contravariance. May be am confused between two different concepts. 
Working on this code below:

```
sealed trait Algorithm[ +T <: Model, P <: Model, R <: AnyVal] {
  def name: String
  def train(trainingData: DenseMatrix[Double]): T
  def predict(row: DenseVector[R], mlModel : P): R
}
```

Then i have two algorithm types declared as:

```
case class LibLinear() extends Algorithm[Active_Linear, Active_Linear, Double] {
  override val name = "libLinear"
  override def train(trainingData: DenseMatrix[Double]): Active_Linear = {
    ........
  }
  override def predict(row: DenseVector[Double], model: Active_Linear): Double = {
    ..........
  }
}


case class SVM() extends Algorithm[Volume_SVM, Volume_SVM, Double] {
  override val name = "libSVM"
  override def train(trainingData: DenseMatrix[Double]): Volume_SVM = {
    ..........
  }
  override def predict(row: DenseVector[Double], model: Volume_SVM): Double = {
    ...........
  }
}
```

Where both `Active_Linear` and `Volume_SVM` are sub types of `Model`.

Now i cannot do this:

```
val algorithm: Algorithm[Model, Model, Double] =  SVM()
```

`SVM` is a sub type of `Algorithm` and `Volume_SVM` is a sub type of `Model`. And We declare `Algorithm` with `covariant` and `contravariant` notations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Algorithm is covariant only when `T` is concerned. `P` and `R` are defined as invariant; you have to precede each of them with `+` or `-` as you need, then modify the code accordingly. Based on your final assignment, I've made some assumptions and that's what I've come up with:

```
sealed trait Algorithm[ +T <: Model, +P <: Model, +R <: AnyVal] {
  def name: String
  def train(trainingData: DenseMatrix[Double]): T
  def predict[U >: R, V >: P](row: DenseVector[U], mlModel : V): U
}

case class LibLinear() extends Algorithm[Active_Linear, Active_Linear, Double] {
  override val name = "libLinear"
  override def train(trainingData: DenseMatrix[Double]): Active_Linear = {
    ...
  }

  override def predict[U >: Double, V >: Active_Linear](row: DenseVector[U], model: V): U = {
    ...
  }
}


case class SVM() extends Algorithm[Volume_SVM, Volume_SVM, Double] {
  override val name = "libSVM"
  override def train(trainingData: DenseMatrix[Double]): Volume_SVM = {
      ...
  }
  override def predict[U >: Double, V >: Volume_SVM](row: DenseVector[U], model: V): U = {
      ...
  }
}
```

Your last assignment then works fine.

Comment: Thanks for taking time and answering this. On a high level i am tempted to accept this answer. The real question (i guess i did not explain well above) is, How do i use the covariant as contravariant as well? The predict method should take the same model returned by train method.

Comment: In java, one can do a <? extends Model> on the method signature, thus allowing us to pass any sub class of model. What is the scala equivalent? or we don't have one?

Comment: What you've done for trait - `T <: Model` for example, does exactly this. Co- and contravariance is another thing; they introduce type hierarchy into your generic type, something that's not exactly possible in Java, if you want to compare. For example, there's immutable `List[+A]` in scala; that means that `List[Integer]` is subtype of `List[Any]`, for example. `+` there means covariance, that is: `List` type hierarchy will follow `A` type hierarchy.